# How to export data from javascript in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yandex-maps

I have a vuejs form and a pure JS-based map widget. I need to extract coords from map (vanilla js) into form input (vuejs). How can I do that?
View:

```
<el-form :model="storeForm" label-width="200px" ref="storeForm" status-icon size="small">
    <el-form-item label="Address" prop="Address">
        <el-input v-model="storeForm.Address" type="textarea"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>
    <el-form-item>
        <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    </el-form-item>
    <el-form-item>
        <el-button type="primary" @click="save('storeForm')">Save</el-button>
        <el-button @click="cancel()">Cancel</el-button>
    </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

And a vuejs code:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isNew: true,
            storeForm: {
                Address: ''
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        ymaps.ready(function () {
            var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                center: [43.241203, 76.957206],
                zoom: 13
            });

            map.events.add('click', (e) => {
                var coords = e.get('coords');

                //obviously that doesn't work
                this.storeForm.Address = e.get('coords');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

`ymaps.ready(function () {`

creates a new scope, so `this` is no longer your Vue app.

Replace with

`ymaps.ready(() => {`

Or add `.bind(this)` at the end of that function.